# How to specify this 'symbolic link' for the Jungo WinDriver?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

Just now , I try to install the Jungo WinDriver in the Ubuntu 13.10 . But I am puzzled by the its manual :

4.2.3. Linux WinDriver Installation Instructions

4.2.3.1. Preparing the System for Installation

In Linux, kernel modules must be compiled with the same header files that the kernel itself was compiled with. Since WinDriver installs kernel modules, it must compile with the header files of the Linux kernel during the installation process.

Therefore, before you install WinDriver for Linux, verify that the Linux source code and the file version.h are installed on your machine:

Install the Linux kernel source code:

If you have yet to install Linux, install it, including the kernel source code, by following the instructions for your Linux distribution.
If Linux is already installed on your machine, check whether the Linux source code was installed. You can do this by looking for 'linux' in the /usr/src directory. If the source code is not installed, either install it, or reinstall Linux with the source code, by following the instructions for your Linux distribution.
Install version.h:

The file version.h is created when you first compile the Linux kernel source code. Some distributions provide a compiled kernel without the file version.h. Look under /usr/src/linux/include/linux to see whether you have this file. If you do not, follow these steps:
Become super user:
$ su
Change directory to the Linux source directory:

## cd /usr/src/linux

Type:

## make xconfig

Save the configuration by choosing Save and Exit.
Type:

## make dep

Exit super user mode:

## exit

To run GUI WinDriver applications (e.g., DriverWizard [5]; Debug Monitor [7.2]) you must also have version 5.0 of the libstdc++ library — libstdc++.so.5. If you do not have this file, install it from the relevant RPM in your Linux distribution (e.g., compat-libstdc++).

Before proceeding with the installation, you must also make sure that you have a linux symbolic link. If you do not, create one by typing

/usr/src$ ln -s 'target kernel'/linux

For example, for the Linux 2.4 kernel type

/usr/src$ ln -s linux-2.4/ linux

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I can't understand how to specify these two parameters in my Ubuntu .

Answer (score 0):

It is just one parameter you need to specify. The last part of the discussion means that installing Jungo WinDriver requires that the kernel code be located in a directory called */usr/src/linux*. In general, however, when you install kernel source code on your system, it is placed in a directory called /usr/src/linux-3.12, or something like that.

So how do you sole the problemof having the source code of in /usr/src/linux, when instead you have it in /usr/src/linux-3.12? You might copy the whol directory /usr/src/linux-3.12 into /usr/src/linux, and this would work, but it would be a total waste of space.

To solve this problem linux provides *symbolic links*, and you may *symbolically link* files or directories (your case). A symbolic link called A to a directory called B means that every time you try to enter A, you actually enter B and find in A whatever is to be found in B, but without knowing even of the existence of B.

So the instruction

```
  ln -s /usr/src/linux-3.12 /usr/src/linux
```

doesthis: it creates a symbolic link called *linux* (the equivalent of A above), which automatically redirects you to *linux-3.12* (the equivalent of B above) without your ever noticing it.

All you have to do then is to check which directory in /usr/src contains the full Kernel code, and substitute it to /usr/src/linux-3.12 above.

Comment: @user252098 If this is the right answer, then you should **accept** it, thank you.

Comment: how to accept ?

Comment: and the problem is not end ,

Comment: please see this:  http://superuser.com/questions/760316/how-to-install-version-h-in-ubuntu