# how to install 'version.h' in ubuntu ?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

Just now , I try to install the Jungo WinDriver in the Ubuntu 13.10 . But I am puzzled by the its manual of how to  Install version.h :

```
Install version.h:

The file version.h is created when you first compile the Linux kernel
source code. Some distributions provide a compiled kernel without the
file version.h. Look under /usr/src/linux/include/linux to see whether
you have this file. If you do not, follow these steps: Become super
user: $ su Change directory to the Linux source directory:
# cd /usr/src/linux Type:
# make xconfig Save the configuration by choosing Save and Exit. Type:
# make dep Exit super user mode:
# exit
```

But the shell says:

> warning: make dep is unnecessary now.

Then, I found out there is a version.h in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0.12-generic, so I type:

```
/usr/src/windriver/redist# ./configure --with-kernel-source=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0.12-generic
```

But, the windriver run fails:

```
USE_KBUILD = yes
checking for cpu architecture... x86_64
checking for WinDriver root directory... /usr/src/WinDriver
checking for linux kernel source... found at /usr/src/linux
checking for lib directory... ln -sf $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/$(SHARED_OBJECT)_32.so /usr/lib/$(SHARED_OBJECT).so; ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64; ln -sf $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/$(SHARED_OBJECT).so /usr/lib64/$(SHARED_OBJECT).so
checking which directories to include... -I/usr/src/linux/include
checking linux kernel version... 3.11.10.6
checking for modules installation directory... /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/misc
checking output directory... LINUX.3.11.0-12-generic.x86_64
checking target... LINUX.3.11.0-12-generic.x86_64/windrvr6_usb.ko
checking for regparm kernel option... find: `/usr/src/WinDriver/redist/.tmp_driver/.tmp_versions': No such file or directory
0
checking for modpost location... /usr/src/linux/scripts/mod/modpost
configure.usb: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating makefile.usb.kbuild

checking for cpu architecture... x86_64
checking for WinDriver root directory... /usr/src/WinDriver
checking for linux kernel source... found at /usr/src/linux
checking for lib directory... ln -sf $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/$(SHARED_OBJECT)_32.so /usr/lib/$(SHARED_OBJECT).so; ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64; ln -sf $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/$(SHARED_OBJECT).so /usr/lib64/$(SHARED_OBJECT).so
checking which directories to include... -I/usr/src/linux/include
checking linux kernel version... 3.11.10.6
checking for modules installation directory... /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/misc
checking output directory... LINUX.3.11.0-12-generic.x86_64
checking target... LINUX.3.11.0-12-generic.x86_64/windrvr6.ko
checking for regparm kernel option... find: `/usr/src/WinDriver/redist/.tmp_driver/.tmp_versions': No such file or directory
0
checking for right linked object... windrvr_gcc_v3.a
checking for modpost location... /usr/src/linux/scripts/mod/modpost
configure.wd: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating makefile.wd.kbuild
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the kernel headers package for your system.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

or first get your kernel version by typing:

```
uname -r
```

In the code below, replace `$version` with your kernel version

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$version
```